# NodeJs testing Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, integration-testing, chai, supertest

I am testing multiple responses but always end up with the same error message:

> ```
> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/this/file/path.js)
> ```

```
   let invalid = 'something_invalid';

    it('With valid appid', (done) => {
        request(server).get(`/game/info/${valid}`)
            .then((err, res) => {

                let json = res.body;

                expect(200);
                expect(json.name).to.equal("Rust");
                done();
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    });
```

Where the response is:

```
{
    "name": "Rust",
    "appid": 252490,
    "description": "The only aim in Rust is to survive - Overcome struggles such as hunger, thirst and cold. Build a fire. Build a shelter. Kill animals. Protect yourself from other players.",
    "publishers": [
        "Facepunch Studios"
    ],
    "price_text": "€33.99",
    "platforms": {
        "windows": true,
        "mac": true,
        "linux": false
    },
    "likes": 374668
}
```

I've looked everywhere but the solution to the problem never solved it.
Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set a longer timeout when running your test:

```
mocha --timeout 10000
```

Or in each suite or each test manually:

```
describe('...', function(){
  this.timeout(10000);

  it('...', function(done){
    this.timeout(10000);
    setTimeout(done, 10000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This will not wait for 10secs, if response came in 7secs it exits the test case, please try this

```
    it('With valid appid', (done) => {
        request(server).get(`/game/info/${valid}`)
            .then((err, res) => {

                let json = res.body;

                expect(200);
                expect(json.name).to.equal("Rust");
                done();
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, 10000);
```